# Retrofit.makeRequest() throws NetworkOnMainThreadException inside RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I am trying to use Retrofit blocking call with RxJava like this:

```
remote = Single.fromCallable(new Callable<List>() {
                    @Override
                    public List call() {
                        try {
                             Response<ApiResponse> execute = makeRequest().execute();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            return new ArrayList();
                        }
                    }
                    ...
```

And I am subscribing:

```
remote
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

But calling execute throws NetworkOnMainThreadException.

I am using

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
```

And in [this](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1069) issue it is said that the bug was fixed but I am still getting it.

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Retrofut supports RxJava using call adapter. Any reason you are not using that?

Comment: https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava2

You can use this adapter, so that your API call will return Observable.
So you do not need to call execute() or enqueue() method.